# Webcam to .Net Core Server to HTML Browser

Tags: .net-core, video-streaming

I'm working on an embedded linux project (still a quad core cpu so plenty of resources). I'm wanting to give options to view camera footage from the system.

I know how to send a static video from a .net core server to the web, but I am unclear how to take YUV footage -> send it to a linux hosted .net core server -> then broadcast it to a subscriber.

Since this is a solved problem trying to not reinvent the wheel. I'm unsure how I should package up the YUV footage. If I encoded it to WebRTC I imagine I could just echo the incoming socket to the server to an outgoing socket and be good. However, I don't know how to do that.

Any recommendations? The initial encoding can use c++ libraries if that is more convenient.

Comment: "If I encoded it to WebRTC I imagine I could just echo the incoming socket to the server to an outgoing socket and be good."  Nope, it's way more complicated than that.  But, there are tools you can use.  Check out gstreamer to start.

Comment: i'd started looking at that. That seems to be the piece I need to get from the starting client to the server. Any recommendations for the next stage? How to handle the incoming connection and prep it to send to the web browser?

Comment: What are your latency requirements?  If you don't need low latency, don't use WebRTC.  You can use something like HLS, which simplifies things quite a bit.

Comment: Kinda depends on what 'low' means in this context as this is my first foray into live streaming software. Ideally on the same network I'd like the latency to be less than a second or two. The current purpose of this largely is so we can live debug issues in the AI and camera system by streaming out different parts of the pipeline to decrease iteration time and easily do diagnostics. However, if it was sub-second on the same network that opens the system up to potentially having remote control capabilities which is being considered. Still investigating a bit what realistic expectations are.

Comment: It is possible to get sub-second latency via a normal stream over a regular HTTP Progressive stream.  Segmented streaming protocols like HLS and DASH add a great deal of latency by their nature.  (There are folks claiming solutions like "low latency DASH" now, but this is effectively getting back to the way HTTP Progressive works, yet with the cruft of DASH.  This is fine if you must use something off-the-shelf, but overly complex otherwise.)  WebRTC will give you the lowest latency, and also handles codec negotiation and all that.  It's probably the route you should go.